# How to Join 3 table in mysql and get result?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 mysql tables where I want to join them and get some results. When I am trying to do this I am geting error in mysql query syntax.

Here is my query syntax

```
select t.id,t.surveyId,t.questionId,t.ansId,t.freeText,t.respondentId,GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(t.ansId AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '~') as ansIds 
from t_survey_responses t 
join t_survey_questions q 
where t.surveyId=336 and t.respondentId=724 and q.questionId=t.questionId 
join t_repondents r on r.respondentSrcId=992762407447511 
group by t.questionId 
order by q.pageNo asc,q.sortOrder asc
```

Thanks

Comment: voting to close as a TYPO. You had the sql statements out of order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `join` conditions should come before the `where` clause:

```
select t.id,t.surveyId,t.questionId,t.ansId,t.freeText,t.respondentId,GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(t.ansId AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '~') as ansIds 
from t_survey_responses t 
join t_survey_questions q 
join t_repondents r on r.respondentSrcId=992762407447511 -- Here!
where t.surveyId=336 and t.respondentId=724 and q.questionId=t.questionId 
group by t.questionId 
order by q.pageNo asc,q.sortOrder asc
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see two tables in your from clause. Also, that group by isn't going to work when you are selecting so many columns. Could also be issues with the syntax of the cast and concatenation. Give us an error code/message!!!